# IBM Worklight - Push Notifications don't reach the device with company's WiFi

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I have downloaded the sample application for Push Notification Module.

At home, with my personal WiFi the application works fine and notifications reach the device as expected.

However, at work, with my company's WiFi, the application is correctly installed in the device, the access to the worklight server occurs but notifications don't reach the device when I send them.
I took a look to the 'Inbound Rules' in the 'Windows Firewall with Advanced Security' panel and the inbound rules for eclipse.exe are defined as follows:

```
Enabled: Yes
Local Address: Any
Remote Address: Any
Protocol: UDP
Local Port: Any
Remote Port: Any
Allowed Users: Any
```

The strange thing is that some days ago I've done it here at work (worked however unstable, sometimes worked sometimes not) but, I have no idea why, it stopped working at all.

I think that would be something about permissions or ports, I don't know, because as I said, at home works fine.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk with your IT department and have them make sure that all required ports are open and accessible to incoming and outgoing requests, as detailed in the Push Notifications training module.

Page #44
http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/09_04_Push_notifications.pdf

Comment: Hi, idan. The problem was the required ports and the powerful firewall oh my company's WiFi. Thanks.